# Activity has leaked window how to fix this exception

Tags: android

```
public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    ArrayList<Datamodel> list;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContactActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("loading Contact");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean isDbEmpty = loadContactFromDb();
        _GetLocation();
        if (isDbEmpty) {
            publishProgress("Sync Contact");
            String numbers = fetchContacts();
            list = uploadPhoneNumber(numbers);
            System.out.println("count :: " + list.size());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(String... strings) {
        pDialog.setTitle(strings[0]);
    }

    public boolean loadContactFromDb() {
        DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(
                ContactActivity.this);
        list = dbManager.fetchContactList(_mylat,_mylong);
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        DBHelper.dbBackup();
        mDataModelArray.clear();
        mDataModelArray.addAll(list);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        schedueService();
        if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
}
    }

}
```

this is my code i am getting Exception at   pDialog.show();                                         at com.lociiapp.ContactActivity$LoadDataTask.onPreExecute(ContactActivity.java:495) 
Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

i have tried to apply condition then also its not working

Comment: try to put this code : publishProgress() inside runOnUiThread().

Comment: what change in code please help me

Comment: you need to create a constructor and pass the context of caller activity or service to that constructor and store it and use it while creating pDialog. Do that way ... it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to continuously check whether the background thread is running or not.

```
if(!isCancelled())
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    dialog.setProgress(valueToUpdate);  
}
else
{
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog=null;
}
```

Comment: i have puted onProgressUpdate method in my code please check that  also tried this code onpostexecute if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
} then also its not working

Comment: Also the checking is required in onPreExecute &  onPostExecute methods

Answer (score 0):

Show the dialog before running the LoadDataTask where it is called

Comment: Are you sure? Can't it be called from `doInBackground()`? If no then what's wrong with it?

Comment: doInbackground executed in seperate thread (not UI thread) - All UI related stuffs should be done in UI(Main) thread